# What does idsrv mean in IdentityServer 3?

Tags: c#, identityserver3, idsrv

Is idsrv the short name for something?

What is idsrv in IdentityServer 3?

As my understanding, is it like the database of identityserver to store the clients, scope, and tokens?

Comment: Are you referring to the idsrv cookie variable?

Answer (score 1):

Identity Server is a framework that allows you to host your own Token Service based on OAuth and OpenID Connect.

The "idsrv" you are referring to, I believe is from the example code and is merely a extension parameter that you can refer to when configuring Identity Server as your middleware. You can rename this to anything you want, and I personally use CoreAppliation as mine.

As above, Identity Server is just (a very comprehensive one) framework, and it is your job to implement the storage of users, client and scopes. You can use the "In Memory" options for very basic implementations, use the built in ASP.Idenity Entity Framework interface or role your own - it really does depend on your own requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I just came across this.

`idsrv` is short for **id**entity **s**e**rv**er. In IdentityServer3's source code I found 80 usages, mostly string constants but also as variable name prefixes. From what I can see, is used simply to save a bit of typing.